# ExpressJs server receives empty request object from VueJS on delete request using axios, but Postman works

Tags: express, vue.js, axios, knex.js, objection.js

I am using ExpressJS with Postgres/Knex/Objection and VueJS on the front end. I have Users, Groups and Memberships s.t. Memberships table associates Users and Groups.

I am attempting to delete a Membership from vue, by sending the `groups_id` and `users_id` to the express route.

Everything works in Postman, but `req.body` is empty on the express side.

On the Vue side, here is my Vue `delete` method:

```
async deleteMembership() {
  await MembershipsService.deleteMembership({
    membership: {
      groupId: this.group.id,
      userId: this.$store.getters.user.id
    }
  });
  this.$emit("membership-deleted");
  console.log('membership has been deleted');
}
```

here is my `MembershipsService`:

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  fetchMemberships () {
    return Api().get('memberships')
  },

  ...

  deleteMembership (params) {
    console.log('these are the request params: ', params);
    return Api().delete('memberships/', params)
  }
}
```

Here is the route from the Express side:

```
router.delete('/', async (req, res) => {
  // deletes a membership
  console.log('this is the req: ', req);
  await Membership
    .query()
    .delete()
    .where('users_id', '=', req.body.membership.userId )
    .andWhere('groups_id', '=', req.body.membership.groupId )
  res.json({
    success: true, message: 'membership deleted' 
  });
});
```

This the body of the working Postman delete request to http://localhost:8000/api/memberships:

```
{
    "membership":
    { 
        "userId": 8,
        "groupId": 1 
    }
}
```

Here is the body of the non-working request on the Vue.js:

```
these are the request params:  {membership: {…}}membership: groupId: 1userId: 8__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
```

This the error on the Express side:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined
```

This is the `req.body` object in Express:

```
body: {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Axios `.delete()`'s second argument is a `config` object.](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosdeleteurl-config) ([TypeScript type definition here.](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L134)) If you want to pass a body, you can use the [`data` config option](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L50):

```js
axios.delete('https://some.url/resource', {data: {foo: 'bar': baz: 123}})
```

In your case (supposing `Api()` returns an axios instance):

```js
deleteMembership (params) {
  console.log('these are the request params: ', params);
  return Api().delete('memberships/', {data: params})
}
```

Demo:

```js
axios.delete('https://reqres.in/api/users/2', {
  data: {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.19.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

Use the developer tools 'Network' tab to inspect the call and see the payload is sent.
```

Comment: Never would have found this.  Thanks!